# Reversing numpy where coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

The objective is to extract the coordinate where a cell equal to 1 in a `2D` array

```
[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Here the coordinate is `flip` than the conventional

```
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Hence, for the `2D` array above,
the output where cell equal to `1` is

```
[(0, 8),(2,4),(3,8)]
```

I curious how can I tweak the `np.where` by taking consideration this type of coordinate.

Simply

```
cor=np.array(np.where(arr==1)).T
```

as expected will give different result than I expect.

The above array can be reproduce

```
arr=np.zeros((9,9))
arr[0,0]=1
arr[4,2]=1
arr[0,3]=1
```

Remark, the order is not important, such that

`[(0, 8),(2,4),(3,8)]` is equivalent to  `[(8, 0),(4,2),(8,3)]`

Comment: Why not just reverse/transpose/etc. the array to the normal order before doing the search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `np.where` for a 2D array returns `Tuple(np.ndarray, np.ndarray)`where the first entry of the tuple contains all row indices and the second one all column indices. So if you want to index the tranposed array you have to swap the tuple entries:

```py
indices = np.where(condition)[::-1]
```

If you want to transform the coordinate format to the list of 2-element-tuple you could do:

```py
indices = [(n_rr, c) for r, c in zip(np.where(condition))]
```

**Edit**:
After clarification, I now understand that rpb wants to change the origin of indexing, so that the zeroth row becomes the last and so on. Furthermore, the coordinates are desired in the format of 2element tuple per found entry.

```py
import numpy as np

arr=np.zeros((9,9))
arr[0,0]=1
arr[4,2]=1
arr[0,3]=1 
print(arr)
print(np.where(arr==1.)[0])

n_rows = arr.shape[0]
indices = [(n_rows - 1 -r, c) for r, c in zip(*np.where(arr==1.))]
print(indices)
>>> [(8, 0), (8, 3), (4, 2)]
```

Comment: Sorry, then I didn't fully understand the issue. What exactly is your desired output? A list of 2-element tuples that each contain (row, col) indices per entry that is equal to 1? If that is the case please have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy flip on axis 0 to flip the array to get your coordinates.

```
arr = np.flip(arr, axis=0)
cor = np.array(np.where(arr==1))
```